# What happens if I get an "I am error" room in the Backasswards challenge?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth, the-binding-of-isaac-afterbirth+

In the new Backasswards challenge, due to the nature of the challenge itself, every trapdoor and hole on the floor is closed shut. What happens if, by chance, I get into an "I AM ERROR" room? Does that end the run since I cannot advance, or the trapdoor to exit the room is replaced by a beam of light (the only way to travel through levels in this challenge)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this is actually an issue that has not been solved yet. Looking at this [Reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/bindingofisaac/comments/5lvis4/afterbirth_megathread_please_read_me_before/):

> IMPORTANT ISSUE: I Am Error rooms break Backasswards
>
> Finding an I Am Error room during the Backasswards challenge leaves you unable to continue, as the only way to exit is to take the trapdoor down. Problem is, Backasswards forcibly closes all downward trapdoors, so you're just stuck.

So you would remain trapped in this room, and wouldn't be able to continue your run.

Comment: Can you get out with another teleport?

Comment: If you can charge your teleport yes but most of the time you need to clear a few rooms to do that.